# Sum LinqToSql Query Without Grouping

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
(from pd in context.Report
where pd.ReportDate.Month == 2012
&& pd.ReportDate.Year == 11 && pd.UserID == 11014
group pd by  pd.UserID  into g
select new 
{                               
    Cost = g.Sum(pd => pd.Cost),
    RevenueUSD = g.Sum(pd => pd.Revenue),
});
```

This Query is

```
 -- Region Parameters
    DECLARE @p0 Int = 2012
    DECLARE @p1 Int = 11
    DECLARE @p2 Int = 11014
    -- EndRegion
    SELECT SUM([t0].[Cost]) AS [Cost], SUM([t0].[Revenue]) AS [RevenueUSD]
    FROM [IntegratedPublisherData] AS [t0]
    WHERE (DATEPART(Month, [t0].[ReportDate]) = @p0) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t0].[ReportDate]) = @p1) AND ([t0].[UserID] = @p2)
    GROUP BY [t0].[UserID]
```

But I Want

```
 -- Region Parameters
    DECLARE @p0 Int = 2012
    DECLARE @p1 Int = 11
    DECLARE @p2 Int = 11014
    -- EndRegion
    SELECT SUM([t0].[Cost]) AS [Cost], SUM([t0].[Revenue]) AS [RevenueUSD]
    FROM [IntegratedPublisherData] AS [t0]
    WHERE (DATEPART(Month, [t0].[ReportDate]) = @p0) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t0].[ReportDate]) = @p1) AND ([t0].[UserID] = @p2)
```

This query will return 1 row because UserID is selected to one value and it's grouped by UserID.

How can I write this Linq query using Sum without grouping?

Comment: Just a quick point, but you've got the report month and year values the wrong way around.

Comment: Is it important that you make *one* roundtrip to the database? Is it important that you only return one row from the database? Is there any reason you can't do this in memory after you've posted the query?

Comment: Do you group because there are multiple rows with the same month, year and userid?

Comment: Can you clarify what you wanna retrieve ? If I understand well (but I'm far from sure about that), you want the Sum of Cost and Revenue for 11/2012. Is it true, or am I far far far away ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes You are right . I need sum of cost and revenue for 11/2012 and userID = 11014.

Comment: You still haven't answered the other questions, pertaining to *how many rows* are likely to be returned, if it needs to be in one roundtrip, et c.

Comment: @J.Steen  Results are same. Both of Queries return same result. Why do I need group it ?

Comment: You're not answering the *questions*. Are there more than one rows returned when you don't group or sum? Knowing the answer to this will impact the validity of the answers below.

Comment: @J.Steen IT'll return more than one rows. IF I don't sum.

Comment: Note: It's not possible to use the `sum` aggregate at all unless the query is grouped, but using `sum` without grouping (in SQL) will make an implicit group of the entire result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also cover your problem, if there are multiple rows returned from the query. Also works for a single row.

```
var query = 
    (from pd in context.Report
     where pd.ReportDate.Month == 11
     && pd.ReportDate.Year == 2012 
     && pd.UserID == 11014
     select pd).ToList() //use .ToList() to avoid doubled execution
var result = 
    new 
    {
        Cost = query.Sum(pd => pd.Cost), 
        RevenueUSD = query.Sum(pd => pd.Revenue) 
    };
```

Comment: Note: This will run the query twice.

Comment: Yes, it's important to note - because OP *still* hasn't clarified - that this makes two roundtrips. I'm fairly sure it's not easy to sum two fields without grouping in linq, in one query.

Comment: If we add `.ToList()` at the declaration of query, there will be no doubled execution.

Comment: Indeed, then there will be only one roundtrip. However, it will then return multiple rows instead of just one. Again, it all depends on the needs and requirements of the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the grouping, and read the values from the table. You don't need `sum` when there is a single record:

```
from pd in context.Report
where pd.ReportDate.Month == 2012 && pd.ReportDate.Year == 11 && pd.UserID == 11014
select new {                               
   Cost = pd.Cost,
   RevenueUSD = pd.Revenue,
 }
```

Comment: There *might* be more rows that have the same UserID. But we won't know that until we ask OP, I guess.

Comment: Not my downvote, by the way. I find the answer almost as helpful as Jan P.'s, without further information.

Comment: This answer is right as mine is, by assumin `UserID` is the primary key of the table. This isn't precisely determined in the question.

Comment: @JanP. UserID is not Primary Key. So I use Sum(). But I know UserID and I dont need to get UserID from query.

Comment: Then my answer is the one you need.